# intern.js How to test legacy non modular code

Tags: testing, legacy, intern

I'm using intern.js as a test framework to test dojo modules and it works well.

Now I have to test some non modular legacy code but I can't.

This is an example of a simple file to test:

```js
var Component = function() {
  this.itWorks = function() {
    return true;
  }
};
```

And this is the test

```js
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'intern/order!controls/component',
], function (registerSuite, assert) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'test legacy code',

        'simple test': function () {
            console.log(Component);
        }
    });
});
```

The test fails sayng that "Component is not defined".

I've notice that it works only if I write

> window.Component = Component

At the bottom of file to test.

I can't modify all the file to test, is it possible to test the file in a different way?

Comment: How are you loading your file, and how are you loading Intern? Are you testing in a Node environment or a browser (I'm guessing a browser because of `window`).

Comment: I'm using Intern web page to run tests, I'm in a browser environment.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine. One possible issue is where you're loading `component` from. The 'controls/component' dependency in `'intern/order!controls/component'` is, barring any special loader config, relative to the file doing the loading. That means that if the project is setup like this:

```
project/
    controls/
        component.js
    tests/
        intern.js
        componentTest.js
```

and `component` is being loaded from `componentTest.js`, then the dependency should be `'intern/order!../controls/component.js'`. (It will actually work without the '../' in this case since `controls` is a top level directory in the project.)

Another potential issue is that a non-AMD identifier should use the `.js` suffix. This tells the loader that the thing being loaded is a generic script rather than an AMD module.

Also note that the `order` plugin is only needed to load multiple legacy files in a specific order. If order doesn't matter, or you're just loading one script, you can just use the script itself `'../controls/component.js'` as the dependency.

Comment: Thank you @jason0x43 but the module (or js) is correctly loaded. The problem is that I can't see the class inside the test. I see it only if I do window.Component = Component. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Could you post a complete example somewhere? Also, what browser are you using? I've setup an example myself based in the description here and tested it in Chrome, and it worked fine, so there must be some other condition I'm missing. Assigning `window.Component = Component` at the bottom of a test file shouldn't be accomplishing anything, because if you can see `component` to do the assignment, then it's already visible in the test scope.

Comment: I've find the mistake! I'am using dojo 1.8 to load modular scripts. As documentation says this: **An explicit path or URL to a script can be passed as a module identifier. In this case, the script is simply evaluated and the return value of that “module” is undefined**. So it will not work. You can got it work putting the aysnc:true in the Intern.js dojo config.

Comment: It will work fine with 1.8; as it says, the script is evaluated (meaning your class gets loaded into the global scope), and the value of the module is undefined, but only if it's a parameter in the `define` callback. That just means that it would be undefined in this case: `define([
..., 'controls/component' ], function (..., Component) { ... });`

Answer (score -1):

<"/"https://stackoverflow.com/tags" term="legacy" /">

<"/!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false --"/">

```
"var Component" = function() {
  "this.itWorks" = function() {
    return=true;
  }
};
```

<"/"!-- end snippet --"/">